# Grappelli/Django IE9/10 compatibility issues

Tags: django, django-admin, django-grappelli

I recently installed the Grappelli theme for my Django project. It looks fine in all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera) except Explorer 9 & 10.

here's an example from chrome:

[image: Chrome]

and here's an example from IE10:

[image: IE 10]

What could be the problem?

Thanks

EDIT: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565733/django-grappelli-seems-unable-to-see-all-its-media-files) post, tried everything there, still no luck.